# remove localstorage array object base on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Says I have this saved key in my localstorage, how to remove the player_id that has value of 2 and shoe size_of 1?

```
[{"player_id":1,"shoe_size":3},{"player_id":2,"shoe_size":1},{"player_id":2,"shoe_size":2},
```

What to do next after I get the saved value?

```
if(localStorage["player"]){
    player = JSON.parse(localStorage["player"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
player  = player .filter(function( obj ) {
    return !(obj.player_id == 2 && obj.shoe_size == 1);
});
```

If you want to set it:

```
localStorage["player"] = JSON.stringify(player)
```

```js
var player = [{"player_id":1,"shoe_size":3},{"player_id":2,"shoe_size":1},{"player_id":2,"shoe_size":2}];

player  = player.filter(function(obj) {
    return !(obj.player_id == 2 && obj.shoe_size == 1);
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(player))
```

Comment: is filter a jquery function or pure js?

Comment: can it be this.player_id instead of obj.player_id?

Comment: yes,thanks so much! but can I it use map or grep? What's the advantage of using filter()?

Comment: @AaronMusktin `Array.prototype.map()` returns one element for every element in the original array. `Array.prototype.filter()` returns only the specific elements that return `true` in the function provided. They are used in different situations.